# Two divs: height auto and 100%

Tags: html, css

I have body with height 100%. And two child divs. Is is possible to make:

1. First div height equals to content height
2. Second div height equals to all other free space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery, once the dom is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#second').css({
        'height': ($('body').height() - $('#first').height()) + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, but will you need to adjust the height if in case the content on the first div changes dynamically??

Comment: @NejiHyuga yes. `document.ready` will wait until any initial assets are loading into the DOM, but all future DOM manipulations of `#first` will need to re-run the height calculation

Comment: @NejiHyuga yes, you will need to adjust in that case

Comment: So it's impossible (too difficult) to do it by css?

Comment: @MaratFaskhiev It is impossible as far as I know